# Change nested objects to the same object whose values which are objects are the objects with parents as prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain

Experimenting with an idea. Given an object like:

```
T = {
  a: 2,
  b: 9,
  c: {
    a: 3,
    d: 6,
    e: {
      f: 12
    }
  }
}
```

I want to mutate it such that every value that is an object, changes to the same object, with the parent object as prototype.

Meaning I'd like to be able to have the following outputs:

```
> T.c.b
9
> T.c.e.b
9
> T.c.e.a
3
> T.c.c.c
{a: 3, d: 6, e:[Object]}
```

I have already created the following functions that work almost as expected:

```
function chainer(object) {
    for (const key in object) {
        if (object[key] !== null && typeof (object[key]) === 'object') {
            let Constructor = function () {
            };
            Constructor.prototype = object;
            let objectValue = {...object[key]};
            object[key] = new Constructor();
            for (const savedKey in objectValue) {
                object[key][savedKey] = objectValue[savedKey];
            }
        }
    }
}

function chain(object) {
    chainer(object);
    for (const key in object) {
        if (object[key] !== null && typeof (object[key]) === 'object') {
            chainer(object[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

With the previous example it works as expected. Nevertheless, when I try with the following:

```
T = {a:4, g:{g:{g:{g:{g:{g:{g:{}}}}}}}}
```

The following output happens:

```
> T.a
4
> T.g.a
4
> T.g.g.a
4
> T.g.g.g.a
undefined
> T.g.g.g.g.a
undefined
```

I find it weird it only works up to a point, it makes me think perhaps its an issue with some limit I'm not aware.

Anyway, I'm getting dizzy and out of ideas, any thoughts?

Comment: Looking at the prototype of `t.g.g.g` it seems to become `{}`. Is there btw any reason why you want to use in place mutation and not return a new object?

Comment: Not really, I guess I'll try to make it pure and see if that works, I'll be on it

Comment: Still didn't work :/

Comment: btw, [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) does not need parenteses, because it's an operator.

Comment: What would be your expectation when you change `T.a` afterwards?

Comment: Thanks, nice to know, I also changed it to use the Object.create ES5 introduced I wasn't aware of

Comment: Would [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/69qp1fkj/1/) fit your description, or am I seeing/understanding it wrong?

Comment: Thanks @Icepickle, that's a good reason to mutate it. With the "pure" version I just made the values weren't updating as I wanted.

Comment: let me check,@Icepickle

Comment: Just checked it, I want the parent value to be percolated down to the childs when changed. I'll study your solution on a bit, thanks alot

Comment: Can you update your code with `Object.create` or `Object.setPrototypeOf`, please? That `constructor` thingy is really confusing.

Comment: Wouldn't you be looking into something like a tree object that just gets things from the parent or undefined if nothing exists? I would say like a context with child contexts? I guess it would be easy to do with indexers in C# in javascript, maybe the Proxy would actually be of help to do some things for you

Comment: I guess another question would be, what should happen with new properties on the object, or do you wish only to chain the ones that were there when this thing got defined?

Comment: Indeed, those are good questions, haven't read about Proxy, seems really interesting and more robust for using this experiment and handling new properties, I'll be checking it out. Thanks for your interest @Icepickle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work fine:

```js
ouroboros = (x, parent = null) => {
    if (!x || typeof x !== 'object')
        return x;
    let r = Object.create(parent);
    Object.entries(x).forEach(([k, v]) => r[k] = ouroboros(v, r));
    return r;
};

//


T = ouroboros({x: 4, a: {b: {c: {d: {e: {}}}}}});
console.log(T.a.b.c.a.b.c.a.b.c.a.b.c.a.b.c.x);
```

or, mutating objects, instead of copying:

```
ouroboros = (x, parent = null) => {
    if (x && typeof x === 'object') {
        Object.setPrototypeOf(x, parent);
        Object.values(x).forEach(v => ouroboros(v, x));
    }
};
```

Comment: Nicer and simpler, thanks a lot, still not sure what was wrong with the original approach.

Comment: @JoshuaMartínez: I guess your code doesn't work for depths > 2 because it's not recursive (2nd function invokes the 1st two times and then stops)

Comment: My god, I can't believe I'm so silly, I was changing function names got mixed up and thought I was doing recursion on `chain`.. I hate when that happens

Comment: Well, at least it was a fun afternoon

Comment: @JoshuaMartínez: yeah, happens all the time... the sillier the mistake, the harder it is to track.

Comment: btw, just for completeness, `typeof(null)` is `object` so a small condition on the ifs is needed

Comment: You might want to default the `parent = null` to `Object.prototype` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaking you wanted to do something like this:

```
rec = function (o) {
  return Object.keys(o).reduce((acc, key) => {

    if (typeof acc[key] === "object") { 
      const kv = {...rec(acc[key]), ...o}
      return {...acc, ...kv, get [key]() { return this}} 
    }
    return acc;
  },o)
}
```

Comment: This is a really clever usage of the getters, and indeed seems to be working as expected. 
Haven't finished getting my head around it, but just wondering, why in `kv = {...rec(acc[key], ...o}` is that order and not the other way around to take the computed object to have priority of the properties over the parents'.
Thanks, I'll leave it open for a while to see if someone comes with other solutions before accepting yours.

Comment: Notice that spread syntax destroys the getter. `Object.assign(acc, kv, {[key]: acc})` would have the same result (as would `acc[key] = acc;`).